# Создание нового типа для ЗП 1С

Tags: 1с

Досталась в наследство 1С 8.2, изучать только начал, мало понимаю. Перелопатил всю систему, вроде бы все ок, все должно работать но нет. Подскажите, что значит эта желтая хрень возле кода? У всех есть а у того что добавил нету, отличий не нашел :(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получил ответ [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/1c/thread1968181.html). Текст ответа :

Объект предопределен в конфигурации, без кружка обычный элемент справочника и в коде вы не сможете к нему обратиться Справочники.МойСправочник.Тип13, его придется искать по коду или по наименованию, типа Справочники.МойСправочник.НайтиПоКоду("000000018") или Справочники.МойСправочник.НайтиПоНаименованию("Тип13").

Грубо говоря предопределенные элементы являются реквизитами справочника, а обычные его наполнением.